# How to handle all routes express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There is a nodejs (express) app.
It has few router handlers.
I want the app after getting SIGTERM to respond with 500 status to all the routes.
How can I achieve that?
I tried:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('SIGTERM CATCHED');

    app.use((req, res) => {
        console.log('RESPONDING PROPERLY')
        res.sendStatus(500);
    })
});
```

But that would definitely not override the more specific handlers.
Additionally, I shouldn't shutdown the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a session variable that you set to 'true' once a SIGTERM is caught (catched if you want :) ). Then you define a middleware that tests if this session variable is false then next() else res.sendStatus(500).